# Additive Smoothing for Dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, smoothing, naivebayes

I have a large dataframe in Pandas with lots of zeros. 
I want to apply additive smoothing but instead of writing it from scratch, I am wondering if there is any better way of producing a "smoothed" dataframe in Pandas. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additive smoothing is just a basic mathematical operation, requiring few additions and division - there is no "special" function for that, you simply write a one-liner operating on particular columns of your dataframe.

Comment: DataFrame.add, e. g., is also just addition. However, they do have such a function because it comes in handy. And you don't necessarily need to downvote my question.

Comment: I did not downvote the question, and do not think it should be downvoted (which is why I posted an answer). Add is provided because it has multiple additional features (parametrized broadcasting, dealing with na values), and at the same time is very generic operation for data. Additive smoothing on the other hand is strictly related to empirical estimates of probabilities, thus very specific usage (as compared to generality of dataframes).

Comment: I stumbled across this Q because I wanted a quick equation, but I then realised it makes total sense there isn't a pre-made one. Yes, it is just `df['smooth_count'] = df['count'].apply(lambda v: (v+alpha)/(N+alpha*d)*N)` where `d = len(df['count'])` but  _N_, the number of trials, might not be `df['count'].sum()` and alpha, smoothing parameter, is up to the user (default: 1). Thinking about what to use for these two takes more effort that the writing the equation...